# fabric.js: 4.2 control does not show when select object

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, canvas, fabricjs

I'm just download fabric.js from http://fabricjs.com/build/ with select all and just simple code as below.

```
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var rect = new fabric.Rect({ width: 79, height: 59, left: 190, top: 100, fill: '#f55', strokeWidth: 1, stroke: 'black' });
canvas.add(rect);
```

There is no rotate and resize control at all and also

```
canvas.item(0).set({
borderColor: 'red',
cornerColor: 'green',
cornerSize: 6
})
```

would not work.
Any suggestion for this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build look like to be broken, you can download fabric.js with npm (https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric) or download the release from the github page: https://github.com/fabricjs/fabric.js/releases/tag/v4.2.0